# Como manter uma imagem em um formulário?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, delphi-xe8, firemonkey

Olá! Para utilizar em produção de jogos, gostaria de entender como manter uma imagem em um formulário através do Firemonkey. O código que tenho até o momento é o seguinte:

```
program TestCase;

uses
    UITypes,   Classes,      Types,
    FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Objects;

type
    TMainForm = class(TForm)
        constructor CreateNew(AOwner: TComponent; Dummy: NativeInt = 0); Override;
        procedure AppEnd(Sender : TObject; var Action : TCloseAction);
        procedure PaintStuff(Sender : TObject; Canvas : TCanvas);
    end;

var
    T : TThread;
    B : TBitmap;
    F : TMainForm; 

{ TMainForm }


procedure TMainForm.AppEnd(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
    T.Terminate;
    Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
    Application.Terminate;
end;

constructor TMainForm.CreateNew(AOwner: TComponent; Dummy: NativeInt = 0);
begin
    inherited CreateNew(nil);
    with TPaintBox.Create(Self) do
    begin
        Width   := ClientWidth;
        Height  := ClientHeight;
        Parent  := Self;
        OnPaint := PaintStuff;
    end;
    OnClose := AppEnd;
end;

procedure TMainForm.PaintStuff(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas);
begin
    Canvas.BeginScene();
    Canvas.DrawBitmap(B, ClientRect, ClientRect, 100);
    Canvas.EndScene;
end;    

begin
    Application.Initialize;
    B := TBitmap.CreateFromFile('test.png');
    B.SetSize(90, 100);
    F := TMainForm.CreateNew(nil);
    F.Show;
    T := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure() begin
        F.Invalidate;
        TThread.Sleep(10);
    end);
    T.Start;
    Application.Run;
end.
```

O trecho acima não lança nenhuma exceção e segundo o *debugger*, todo o código está sendo executado. No entanto a imagem não é mostrada.

Estou esquecendo algo? Preciso de mais alguma configuração que não estou sabendo? Estou fazendo tudo errado? Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Você tentou desenhar sem o bitmap? Por que motivo você está utilizando uma thread nesse exemplo?

Comment: De outra maneira eu precisaria de um `TTimer`, mas como precisarei de outros processamentos preferi uma _thread_. No entanto já descobri o problema.Eu estou utilizando o `SetSize` logo após a criação do `TBitmap` e carregamento da imagem. E isso aparentemente apaga o conteúdo atual do `TBitmap`. Sem o `SetSize` o código acima funciona.

Comment: neste caso, você mesmo deveria responder essa pergunta.

Comment: @Guill, teria como alterar seu código e adicionar como resposta? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dito nos comentários, por qualquer motivo o método `SetSize` apaga o conteúdo atual do *bitmap*. Sendo assim, remover a chamada a este método faz com que a imagem se mantenha no formulário.

No caso da necessidade de definir o tamanho da imagem, deve-se seguir esta ordem:

1. Criar o objeto `TBitmap`.
2. Definir o tamanho com `SetSize`.
3. E apenas finalmente, carregar uma imagem com `LoadFromFile`.